# SQL | Criteria Query for max value in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I need to find out the row corresponding to the row in table2 which gives a single row output for the below query.
I will be writing a JPA criteria query for this query.
I am able to get the max(date) from the subquery but not the exact row (corresponding to this max value) for the table2.

```
SELECT table2.ER AS col_0_0_,
       table1.CR AS col_1_0_
FROM table1 table1 CROSS
JOIN table2 table2
WHERE table2.date=
    (SELECT max(table2i.date)
     FROM table3 table3 CROSS
     JOIN table2 table2i
     WHERE table2i.id=table2.id
       AND table2i.FC=?
       AND table2i.TC=?
       AND table2i.TCOB=?
       AND table2i.FCOB=?
       AND table2i.TC=table1.id
       AND table2i.RT=?
       AND table2i.RTOB=?
       AND table3.id=?
       AND table2i.date<=table3.CD)
```

Comment: What is the primary key of Table 2?

Comment: @TabAlleman The cloumn "id" is the primary key of Table2

Answer (score 0):

To limit your join to a single row, instead of joining on the date, join on the id:

```
WHERE table2.id=(
  SELECT TOP 1 table2i.id
  FROM table2 table2i
  CROSS JOIN table3 
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY date DESC
)
```

the ORDER BY date DESC forces it to choose a row that has the highest date value, but limits it to only one row (top 1).

Answer (score 0):

Using below solved the issue :

```
SELECT table2.ER AS col_0_0_,
       table1.CP AS col_1_0_
FROM CV table1 CROSS
JOIN ER_VIEW table2
WHERE table2.FCI=?
  AND table2.TCI=?
  AND table2.TCOB=?
  AND table2.FCOB=?
  AND table2.TCI=table1.id
  AND table2.RTI=?
  AND table2.RTOB=?
  AND table2.date=
    (SELECT max(table2i.date)
     FROM DATE_VIEW table3 CROSS
     JOIN ER_VIEW table2i
     WHERE table2i.FCI=?
       AND table2i.TCI=?
       AND table2i.TCOB=?
       AND table2i.FCOB=?
       AND table2i.RTI=?
       AND table2i.RTOB=?
       AND table3.id=?
       AND table2i.date<=table3.CD)
```